# Running .Net Core Application On Mac Without Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, .net-core, coreclr

I am wondering is there a way to run a .net core application on Mac with the terminal/console window open. It just need to run in background without any terminal window open.

I think

> apple script

can do it. But is there any other recommended way to do it

Comment: Have you looked into `launchctl`? That lets you start processes at login that run in the background.

Comment: I am aware of launchctl/launchd and I think it will be too cumbersome - load,start,stop,unload for a simple task of just launching a process in background without terminal window